# Finding relevant smart contract information in Blockchain data

Tags: ethereum, analytics, smartcontracts

First of all apologies for probably poorly named question but the fact that I can't formulate it better is probably partially a reason why I've not been successful in finding the answer. I am trying to understand where in blockchain data can I find specific value of smart contract method. For instance, as in the screen below, this specific smart contract `0xF59D66c1d593Fb10e2f8c2a6fD2C958792434B9c` holds information about the totalAssets and pricePerShare. I can see the values in the Etherscan but now, having access to logs/events and transactions from Ethereum blockchain- can I find these values in either logs/events/transactions? And how would I go about finding that value per block in the past? Any hints how to approach it would be very helpful [image: Screen from Etherscan]

Answer (score 1):

To get historical data, you can refer to the smart contract view function indicating the block number at the time of which you want to view the result. For example, for JSON RPC, such a request looks like:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"to":"contract", "data":"function signature and parameters"}, "block number"], "id":1}") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details on Biqtuery's explorer
https://explorer.bitquery.io/ethereum/token/0xf59d66c1d593fb10e2f8c2a6fd2c958792434b9c

The smartcontract you have mentioned is the Curve OUSD Pool yVault (yvCurve-OUSD) ERC20 Token.